# Edit html file to add spsecurityTrimmedControl in SP 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, master-page

I want to edit the html file for the master page to add SPSecurityTrimmedControl but am not sure how to edit that in SharePoint 2013, I know how to edit the master page directly, am not familiar with how it is in SharePoint 2013.

Comment: any ideas anyone????????

Answer (score 1):

you can edit the masterpage with the **SharePoint Designer 2013**. You can download it directly from microsofts website - [SharePoint Designer 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30346). Unfortunaly it doesn't work with Mac OS, only Windows.

After installing it you can connect to the SharePoint Site. You'll find the HTML masterpage (e.g. oslo.html or seattle.html) at the master page gallery (*/_catalogs/masterpage/*).

Comment: Please take a copy and edit the copy instead of the original masterpage though! Then configure your site(s) to use the copy.